# MVC + Bootstrap & Partial views Ajax Loaded content

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm currently buidling an application using bootstrap and mvc, along with jQuery, and i'm with some questions, regarding the best approach for using this all frameworks together.

I've a View, which on `$(document).ready()` calls my function `ns.component.load({})` => load's and Partial View using ajax. But this partial view has some bootstrap elements, such as tooltip. If my view, its loaded without ajax, the tooltip works just fine, because the bootstrap library initializes by binding on `$(function() { $('.tooltip').tooltip({})}`. I dont want to, each time i have to use my 'components', have to explicitly start a `$('.tooltip').tooltip()` or any other component, inside each view or partial view, and also pollutes the views, with repeated bootstrap components initialization.

In my _Layout view, I already have declared the scripts bundles for this libraries. But the dynamic content is messy.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following to bind the tooltips function to the dynamically added elements in your DOM

```
$('body').tooltip({
    selector: '.tooltip'
});
```

Bonus:

For other dynamically added DOM elements that you want to bind, for example, the click event, you can use

```
$(document).on('click', '.myClass', function(){
   // do something
});
```

Comment: Can you provide some jquery documentation on how the first snippet works?